# Retrieving the selected HTML from a contenteditable div

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm trying to get the selected HTML from a contenteditable div in a particular situation. First of all let me tell you that i read the questions from [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) and [Get Selected HTML in browser via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083682/get-selected-html-in-browser-via-javascript).

and that i am using Redactor http://imperavi.com/redactor/

So I tried the following function to retrieve the selected HTML:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```

Now the situation is this: i have something like an italic text, then i select it and i modify the DOM to make it look bolded too.

1. When i select the text and make it bolded, the HTML i get looks like this:

   ```
   <span class="bold">​</span><strong><span class="bold" data-redactor="verified" data-redactor-inlineMethods="">fermentum</span><span></span></strong>
   ```
2. I click somewhere else within the page. The text is deselected.
3. When i select the text for the second time and i make it italic i get the following:

   ​*fermentum*

As you can see, the second time i don't get the elements which allow me to determine that it is bolded.

So, it DOESN'T WORK on Internet Explorer 10.
It WORKS on Firefox.
It DOESN'T WORK on Chrome.

**Is there an effective way to get the selected HTML from a contenteditable div other than this one?**

Comment: It sounds like you want the HTML to contain all the styling information, including styling inherited from elements that contain the selection. Is that right? What do you actually need to do with this?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your answer. I get the HTML, wrap it in a div using a string and pass this string to jQuery for parsing it. Then i traverse it recursively to collect all the elements and styles that could affect the text properties (like <b>, <strong> for bolded, <em>, <i> for italic, font-size: 12px for the font size, and so on). So the main idea is to know all the styles/tags applied to a certain text within the contenteditable div to activate them in a toolbar. @TimDown