# Froala editor keep indent when pasting code

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, indentation, paste, froala

I'm having some trouble with pasting into Froala. I have a custom code button which adds the `<pre><code>Code here</code></pre>` tags:

```
$('textarea[name="description"]').editable({
    customButtons: {
        insertCode: {
            title: 'Insert code',
            icon: {
                type: 'font',
                value: 'fa fa-code'
            },
            callback: function() {
                if (!this.selectionInEditor()) {
                    this.$element.focus(); // Focus on editor if it's not.
                }

                var html = '<pre><code>' + (this.text() || '&#8203;') + '</code></pre>';

                this.insertHTML(html);
                this.saveUndoStep();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to be able to paste code into the editor, remove the styling but keep the linebreaks and indent. Similiar as here on SO with `CNTL+K`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `this.text()` with something that gets the selected HTML and not the selected text. Froala WYSIWYG Editor doesn't has such mechanism, but you could use the answer from [Get Selected HTML in browser via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083682/get-selected-html-in-browser-via-javascript) question.