# How to copy the selected HTML without modifying the format - iOS extension

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

Here is the scenario. For iOS share extension, the user selects the content in the safari and taps the share button.

[Safari screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ0ro.png)

What I need is, to get the selected html without any modification in its format.

I can get the selected HTML by using the  [Get Selected HTML in browser via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083682/get-selected-html-in-browser-via-javascript) "Stofke" answer in Extension preprocessor.

But the problem here is the css properties are not mapped to the HTML, so it doesn't look same as safari.

Does anyone help me resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, to get those computed properties on the cut fragment, the user/OS must issue the copy command, JS commands will just grab the bare HTML...

Comment: @dandavis it should work if we can programatically trigger the copy command. but is it possible in javascript?

Comment: no, you can't trigger a copy from JS. well, you could in OLD IE, but who cares?