# Get the HTML source code of the selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a page with a blog article on it. People can select part of this article and I want to store the part they have select, but not just the text on screen, the HTML source.

Example, the screen shows;

> The Boerboel Breeders Association was **established in 1983** in the Senekal district.

Where the full code is:

```
<p>
    The Boerboel Breeders Association was <strong>established in 1983</strong> in the Senekal district.
</p>
```

So I want that when somebody selects "was established in 1983 in the Senekal district" it returns to me the source code as per:

```
was <strong>established in 1983</strong> in the Senekal district
```

I am using Javascript & jQuery.

Comment: how you are getting selected in you case without html tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083682/get-selected-html-in-browser-via-javascript

Comment: One question ... you want the comple p tag or just the strong tag ?

Comment: @TusharGupta it was just for the strong tag, not the parent one. I selected the right answer, works great :)

Comment: Ok if that was the case....the answer was already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643635/how-to-get-selected-html-text-with-javascript. Plagiarism is not good. Rest is upto the moderators