# how to get selected DOM using javascript if selected text is HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a div which displays HTML on a page.
I can get selected text using
`window.getSelection();` it returns node list.
Also tried `window.getSelection().toString();` it returns string.

What I need is selected DOM instead of text or node list.I want to add data-child attribute when text is selected using javascript only.

so, if displayed text is `<div>xyz</div>`, It should become `<div data-child="id-1">xyz</div>` after selection.

Comment: *"it returns node list"* - Doesn't it return a `Selection` object? Anyway, what do you want to do if the user selects a bigger range of text that includes some from your div and some from the element before or after the div?

Comment: @nnnnnn I will discard that selection. User will be allowed to select only a complete node.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/5083682/104380

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176923/104380

Comment: You are asking **two entirely separate** questions. first, is getting the selection as `html` and second one is modifying the result and replacing the selected node with the modified node.

Comment: hey @vsync ,I just want to get selection as HTML.
I described it to let all know ,why I wanted to get it and why only tostring() is not sufficient.
Trying answers posted here and the given reference question.

Comment: Well, did the related links I've placed in the comments helped? this is some advanced DOM stuff, you need a lot of patience until you stitch it all correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach.. (if only you've direct text node in your div)

```
window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement     //returns the selected element
```

so you can set attr like

```
window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.setAttribute('data-id', 'id-1');
```

You can wrap it in a 'mouseup' event with your current div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id natus voluptatibus eum explicabo soluta excepturi?
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id natus voluptatibus eum explicabo soluta excepturi?
    </div>

    <script>
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv')
        myDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
            window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.setAttribute('data-id', 'id-1');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or it is best approach to add attr to selected 'div' only, if there is many divs

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div')
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
    div[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
     window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement.setAttribute('data-id', 'id-1');
    }, false)
}
```